# Changing queryset of a ModelChoiceField on Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to display a dropdownlist showing only some objects in a queryset, but either I am getting an error, or I am displaying none, or I am displaying all.

```
models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='') 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class DropDownList(forms.Form):
    switch = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Book.objects.none().order_by('name'), widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'submit()'}), required=False, initial=0)

    def __init__(self, u, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DropDownList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
        self.fields['switch'].queryset = Book.objects.filter(owner = u)


views.py
d = DropDownList('anthony')
```

When I try to syncdb I get: *"NameError: name 'u' is not defined*
I have tried to filter using other methods like `get(Q(owner = u))` to no avail.
I am following the info from this snippet http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2481/
The dropdownlist was correctly shown when I didn't filter the items it contains.

Comment: The code as pasted would not give that error. Please check for any indentation problems, tabs vs spaces, and post the full traceback.

Comment: sorry, I had forgotten to write the "super(..).__init__..." sentence. now I get that error

Comment: it was indeed an indentation error. now it works! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your code:

1. If you override the `__init__` method, don't forget to call `super(...).__init__`:

   ```
   class DropDownList(forms.Form):
       switch = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Book.objects.none().order_by('name'), widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange": 'submit()'}), required=False, initial=0)

       def __init__(self, u, *args, **kwargs):
           super(DropDownList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.fields['switch'].queryset = Book.objects.filter(owner=u)
   ```
2. Maybe just mistyping in question, but be sure, that you've used `max_length` arg, and not `max_lenght`:

   ```
   class Book(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
       owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.name
   ```

Comment: I had the super sentence, but forgot to write it. regarding "lenght", it is a typo at my question

Answer (score 1):

If you need a custom filter when the form is used in different view outputs, you can also construct the form normally with no override for init, and then alter the field querysets:

```
def my_view_function():
   switch_query ... view specific filters ...
   form = DropDownList()
   form.fields['switch'].queryset = switch_query 
   ... rest of view render ...
```

Alternatively you could change the constructor to pass in a queryset for these elements too.